# ADSL router - data rate and max rate

Tags: adsl, adsl-router

My ADSL2+ router gives me the following statistics:

SNR Margin: 16.8
Line Attenuation: 25.0
Data Rate: 8192 kbps
Max Rate: 16972 kbps

I don't quite understand Data Rate and Max Rate?
Is Data Rate the current speed I have (with overhead), and Max Rate the max speed my telephone line can handle (based on distance from DSLAM, quality of splitter, etc.)?

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: You are correct data rate is your current speed (your cap) and max is the max speed supported on the line (after attenuation)... However are you sure it is ADSL? it's odd they didn't break down up/down stream speeds... You may have symmetrical DSL which is much better.

Comment: Did you check out the links in the comments to your question on ServerFault?

Comment: @Kyle, thanks for the answer. Yes, it's ADSL. Upstream Data Rate: 1023 kbps, Max rate: 1056 kbps.

Comment: @DaveM, You closed the question as off topic. Link in the comment was pretty much useless because I wanted to know what's the max speed I can get.

Comment: I come here from google and i found this question useful :)